# Digital Ocean spaces not working in the remote environment - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, digital-ocean, laravel-5.5

I used [this](https://joelennon.com/using-digitalocean-spaces-in-laravel) tutorial to define a driver and connect to my spaces on Digital Ocean.

In my `config\filesystems.php` I have this code:

```
'spaces' => [
    'driver' => 'spaces',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
    'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
    'bucket_name' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
],
```

In one of my controllers iI have this code:

```
$client->subdomain = 'acme';

$directories_client = Storage::disk('spaces')->directories('clients/'.$client->subdomain);
```

### Problem

The connection to `spaces` driver works perfectly in my local environment. 
However, in remote environment, this line

`$directories_client = Storage::disk('spaces')->directories('clients/'.$client->subdomain);`

produces error. Here is hat my log says:

```
[2017-09-29 07:19:08] remote.ERROR: Driver [] is not supported. 
{"userId":5,"email":"_________","exception":"[object] 
(InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Driver [] is not supported. at 



/.../src/Illuminate/ Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php:124)
```

The local code works perfectly at the very same time as the remote fails.

Any ideas?

Peter

Answer (score 2):

you need use `s3` as driver name, just change this
`'driver' => 'spaces',` to `'driver' => 's3',`

Comment: An `s3` driver voor digitalocean services?

Comment: yes, digitalocean spaces created same api as s3, so you can use s3 driver